# Feature request: 'Someone write this code for me'

Tags: support, feature-request

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this, but it looks like it, so here it goes.

It would be very useful if there was a special tag or a section for people that don't need an answer but rather want a simple script as an answer. Right now, where do this questions go? They would be easier to spot and answer if they all shared a common tag.

Comment: I doubt these kind of requests would be very well received. If the OP is clearly not searching for knowledge, only solutions, I would guess that fewer potential answerers would donate their time for free.

Comment: This isn't dead, fear not. We're actively looking at a way to integrate this or something along these lines in a way that it's actually useful and not just to appease localized questions. It's our most popular tag so we have to curate it somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

I have a slightly different interpretation of this question, but I agree with the general sentiment that a tag for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on the main site would promote something that the site wasn't intended to provide. My more nuanced view is that we kind of already pick and choose which questions are reasonable "feature requests" - even when they aren't specifically labelled that way.

People will ask all kinds of questions on the main site - Some of these questions are well beyond our scope. Some will be honest 'does this exist? it would really solve this problem x i'm having'. In the best of cases the answer to those is, "No, but it's easy to write a script for it".

I think those of us who solve problems by writing scripts really enjoy showing how relatively simple it is to solve these problems. We tend to respond better to questions that would benefit Blender as a whole, not just the one OP who has some specific need.

Often what makes the scripts seemingly balloon in size/complexity is the Boilerplate needed to (un)register an add-on and operators. Script length doesn't correlate to time / effort.

- Complex problem descriptions can have simple solutions
- Simple problem descriptions can have complex solutions.

---

I think if you want dedicated Scripts you should be looking at a site like the [blender network](https://www.blendernetwork.org/) (by and for Blender professionals).

Or.. bite the bullet and learn Python. That's an investment nobody can take away from you.

Answer (score 3):

Feels like "solve my homework for me" on Stackoverflow. That's generally disliked. That's why this feature request is getting downvoted.

You will have to find a different website for "make this for me" kind of questions/requests, outside the StackExchange sites.